# Is "being solvable" a geometric property for linear algebraic groups?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, solvable-groups

Say $G$ is a solvable linear algebraic group over some field $k$ of characteristic 0. This means that its derived series eventually terminates with a 1. My question is:

> Is "being solvable" a geometric property? By this, I mean: is it true that $G$ is solvable iff $G_{\bar{k}}$ is solvable?

I know that "being virtually solvable" is **not** a geometric property, but it's not clear to me that this holds also for "being solvable"

Details and references in the answers are very welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by $G_k$?

Comment: @SimingTu $G_{\bar{k}}:= G \times_{spec(k)} spec(\bar{k})$ is the base change.

Comment: Why downvote the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true (I'm assuming by ``linear algebraic group" you mean *smooth* affine group), over any field $k$. In fact solvability of $G$ can be checked by checking solvability in the usual group-theoretic sense of $G(K)$ for any algebraically closed field $K$ containing $k$. Combining this with compatibility of the formation of the (smooth) derived $k$-subgroup scheme of $G$ gives what you want (smoothness is what ensures that, over an algebraically closed field $K$, the scheme-theoretic derived series ends in $1$ if and only if the derived series of the abstract group $G(K)$ does).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know any good references to find these and more stuff about solvable groups? Thanks again.